# Catch db error with Doctrine\DBAL\Exception

Tags: database, symfony, exception, doctrine-orm, concrete5-5.7

I want to catch any error (ie: foreign key error) from an `insert` statement or any other. How can I achive that with `use Doctrine\DBAL\Exception`?

I have this when I do the `insert`:

```
            $db->beginTransaction();
            try {
              $db->insert('bbc5.produccionpry',$datos);
              $datos['propryid'] = $db->lastInsertId();
              $db->commit();
              // $db = null;
              $resp[] = $datos;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
              $error = array_merge($error, array('error' => $e->errorInfo()));
              $db->rollback();
              throw $e;
            }
```

But, that doesn't prevent the concrete5 to `return` a website telling about the error, so, I don't want that website to be shown, I want to catch the error in an `array()` in order to return it via `echo json_encode($error)`

I'm not using the controller for a page, I'm using it for managing RESTful calls from my JavaScript App with this code:

```
return fetch(`/scamp/index.php/batchprodpry/${maq}`, { 
  method: 'POST', 
  credentials: 'same-origin', 
  headers: { 
    'Accept': 'application/json', 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
  }, 
  body: JSON.stringify(this.state.a) 
})
```

I'm using ReactJS

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Don't throw the exception.**

Instead of throwing the exception, just get the exceptions message `$e->getMessage()` from the `DBALException $e` object and encode it as a JSON string. **Important:** Put an `exit;` after the `echo` to assure that no further code is executed.

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException;

try {
    $db->insert('bbc5.produccionpry',$datos);
    $datos['propryid'] = $db->lastInsertId();
    $db->commit();
    $resp[] = $datos;
} 
catch(DBALException $e){
    $db->rollback();
    echo \Core::make('helper/json')->encode($e->getMessage());
    exit;
}
```

If this code is inside a page controller you could do this:

```
try {
    $db->insert('bbc5.produccionpry',$datos);
    $datos['propryid'] = $db->lastInsertId();
    $db->commit();
    $resp[] = $datos;
}
catch(DBALException $e){
    $this->error->add($e->getMessage());
}

if($this->error->has()) {
    // All variables that have been set in the view() method will be set again.
    // That is why we call the view method again
    $this->view();
    return;
}
```

And concrete5 will take care of displaying an appropriate error message.

Or you could save the `$e->getMesssage()` in the session and call it inside the view:

```
$session = \Core::make('session');
// ...
catch(Exception $e){
    $session->set('error', $e->getMessage());
}
```

And in the view:

```
// html
<?php 
$session = \Core::make('session');
if($session->has('error')) {
    $m = $session->get('error');
    ?>
    <div id="session_error" class="alert alert-danger">
        <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>

        <div id="session_error_msg">
            <?php  print $m ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php 
}
$session->remove('error');
?>
//html
```

Comment: Hello, I haven't found a solution. I'm gonna try yours. Thank you

Comment: hello, it didn't work. I keeps returning the error website, and I only want the exception message from Mysql

Comment: I'm getting my database connection from: `$db = \Database::connection();`

Comment: Should work like that. Need to see more code then, must be somewhere else

Comment: What happens after the catch block? Do u use the dbal exception? did u put the `exit`? in my code it works though

Comment: Did you try to delete the `beginTransaction` and `rollback`part?

Comment: I did not try it, should I?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120814/discussion-between-daenu-and-rafael-mora).

Comment: Thank you. commenting the `throw $e;` did the work! appreciate your help! @Daenu @Tomasz Madeyski

Answer (score 3):

Since you have `throw $e` in your `catch` block you throw this exception further which means that it is (probably) handled by global exception listener. Once you throw exception you exit your code immediately, so a solution for you is just remove `throw $e` line and you should be good

Comment: Hi, I did that and it still does it. Thank you

Comment: post the rest of your code (what is after catch block)

Comment: `echo` is not enough. Is this code inside a controller? If so try `return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse(json_encode($error))` instead

Comment: Ok I'm gonna try it, will that prevent that c5 shows the default website?

Comment: I'm not familiar with c5 but in Symfony it will prevent default website to render

Comment: I tried it but it did not work. It keeps showing the default error website